# onchange issue in react-datepicker with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, datepicker

```
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(null);

const onChange = (dates: [? | ?]) => {
  const [start, end] = dates;
  setStartDate(start);
  setEndDate(end);
};
```

I want to give 'dates' type.
I gave 'dates' number type, but it's not number type.
what type should i give 'dates'??

please tell me how to apply TypeScript datePicker..

Answer (score 1):

The `Date` object is simply typeof built-in type `Date`.

```
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState<Date>(new Date());
     // ^^^^^ will be typeof Date

const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState<Date | null>(null);

const onChange = (dates: [Date, Date]) => {
```

Comment: thank you for your reply! but.. there's an error 'setEndDate(end)' ===> 

Argument of type 'Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<null>'.
  Type 'Date' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: null): null'.

Comment: @joey Then simply add the type for the second `useState`. `const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState<Date | null>(null);`

Comment: wow.......thank you... Thanks to you, I solved : )

Comment: I have this same issue, my second date is always null

Comment: @FranciscoSouza You can initialize a different value for second date than `null` -> `useState(new Date())`